# Загрузка аватарки при помощи Spatie Media Library

Tags: laravel, media-library

Ошибка The current request does not have a file in a key named `avatar`

Делал по [Инструкции](https://laravel.demiart.ru/uploading-avatar-images/)

Подскажите кто сталкивался ?

Comment: У тебя же в ошибке все написано. Если такого ключа нет, проверь. Возможно в базе нет или по другому у тебя записано не "avatar" а "avatars".

Answer (score 0):

Если делали все по инструкции, то в данной инструкции не прописано, что для передачи файлов через форму, нужно к полю формы добавить

```
enctype='multipart/form-data'
```

Т.е форма регистрации должна начинаться с :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Ну и проверьте правильность названий всех полей.